# Where clause in Haskell using Data.Map

Tags: haskell, graph, functional-programming

I have a little question in a specific senario in Haskell.

My graph :

```
import Data.Map (Map,empty,member,insert,keys,findWithDefault,assocs ,fromList,(!),union,mapWithKey,adjust)
import Graphviz

-- | A directed graph
data Graph v = Graph
    { arcsMap :: Map v [v]     -- A map associating a vertex with its successors
    , labelMap :: Map v String -- The Graphviz label of each node
    , styleMap :: Map v String -- The Graphviz style of each node
    }
```

My function :

```
-- | Replaces the labels of each vertex by an empty string
--
-- >>> g = addArcs emptyGraph [(1,2),(2,3),(1,3)]
-- >>> putStrLn $ graphvizString $ unlabelGraph g
-- digraph {
--     1 [label=""];
--     2 [label=""];
--     3 [label=""];
--     1 -> 2;
--     1 -> 3;
--     2 -> 3;
-- }
-- ...
unlabelGraph :: Ord v => Graph v -> Graph v
unlabelGraph  (Graph arcs labels styles)= (Graph arcs (mapWithKey f labels ) styles)
                                         where f  = adjust "" *the actual key*
```

I want to reach every value of the Map labels to replace them by "".
How can i specify that i want the key of the Map inside the where clause of my function?
Is this the best way to write this function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

unlabelGraph  (Graph arcs labels styles) =
   (Graph arcs (M.mapWithKey f labels) styles)
   where f _key _value = ""
```

Still, you don't really need the key in your `f`, since it will always return the empty string. Hence, we can use

```
unlabelGraph  (Graph arcs labels styles) =
   (Graph arcs (M.map f labels) styles)
   where f _value = ""
```

or even

```
unlabelGraph  (Graph arcs labels styles) =
   (Graph arcs (M.map (const "") labels) styles)
```

or even

```
unlabelGraph g = g{labelMap = M.map (const "") (labelMap g)}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your answer, i tried this code `unlabelGraph :: Ord v => Graph v -> Graph v
unlabelGraph  (Graph arcs labels styles) =
    (Graph arcs (mapWithKey f labels) styles)
    where f key value = "sdhjfgkuewhdoji"    `

I did this to understand what the function does, I do not know why it does not show sdhjfgkuewhdoji in the values ​​of my label map(its empty). Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @VelyynS `map` / `mayWithKey` replace _existing_ values in the map. If you start from an empty map, the result is still empty. Perhaps what you want instead is to replace the values in the `arcs` map, so that you use those keys instead of the one in the `labels` map?